# Puppeteer Scraping for URLs - Returning Null

Tags: hyperlink, puppeteer, href

Trying to create an array of links from a class of elements and it is returning null. How do I get a list of links from this [HTML](https://landa.app/m/feed)?

**INPUT**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getLink(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'false'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    
    const linksRaw = await page.$$eval(
        '.PropertyItem_propertyItem__Fla4I',
        links => links.map(link => link.getAttribute('data-url'))
    );

    console.log(linksRaw)

    await browser.close();
}

getLink('https://landa.app/m/feed');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
  null, null, null, null,
  null, null, null, null,
  null, null, null, null,
  null, null, null, null,
  null, null, null
]
```

Comment: Where is the `data-url` property in the DOM? `document.querySelector("[data-url]")` returns null and `.PropertyItem_propertyItem__Fla4I` has no attributes other than the class. Which links are you expecting? Each property card looks like it's not a real link, probably uses a click event to use JS to trigger the SPA transition to push the new URL. Depending on the data you want, `feed.json` seems to have most of the properties on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On such pages :

- check for recurring piece of text e.g. in *.PropertyItem_propertyItem__Fla4I* there is an 'img' tag with **alt="1363HS-BRK"** and a little lower there is a 'div' tag with **ticker="1363HS-BRK"**
- open the page source in your browser (Ctrl+U), then search for it (Ctrl-F),  in this case you can see it under a script tag with id
- open the detail page of anything on the page and look at how it is formed.

the rest is just getting that script and parsing it.

The following code will get the links :

```js
    async function getLink(url) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'false'});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        
        let raw = await page.$eval('script[id="__NEXT_DATA__"]', el => el.innerText.trim());
        let parsed = JSON.parse(raw);
        let json = parsed.props.pageProps.properties; // check the parsed file to see its structure

        let urls = [];
        for (let el of json) {
            let e = el.address;

            if (e !== undefined) { // bypass those that don't have a address property      
            
                let street = e.street.replace(/\s+/g, '-');  // replace spaces with '-'
                let houseNo = e.houseNumber;
                let city = e.city.name;
                let stateCode = e.state.code;
                let zip = e.zipCode;
                let ticker = el.ticker.replace(/@/g, '_'); // replace @ with '_'

                let url = `https://landa.app/m/property/${street}-${houseNo}-${city}-${stateCode}-${zip}/${ticker}`;

                urls.push(url);
            }

        }

        console.log(urls);

        await browser.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate your response, I thought this thread was dead. I will try out your solution once I can and confirm that it works!